# Sending stream (e.g. file) from actor to actor

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-streams

I want to sent data from a stream in one actor to a stream in another actor. In the end this should work with remote actors. With **Akka.NET Streams** this should be an easy task but maybe I have misconcepted it.

This is part of the **SenderActor**:

```
var stream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open);
var materializer = Context.Materializer();
var source = StreamConverters.FromInputStream(() => stream, CHUNK_SIZE);
var result = source.To(Sink.ActorRef<ByteString>(this.receiver, new Messages.StreamComplete()))
    .Run(materializer);
```

Note: `this.receiver` is an `IActorRef` where the data should be send to.

The ReceiverActor now gets all the `ByteString` messages and `Messages.StreamCompleted` after the stream ended.

How can this easily be put together in the ReceiverActor? In best case as a `Stream` again.

In the **ReceiverActor** I tried to send all that `ByteString` messages to a `Source` which should fill a `MemoryStream`:

```
class ReceiverActor : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly IActorRef streamReceiver;
    private readonly MemoryStream stream;

    public ReceiverActor()
    {
        this.stream = new MemoryStream();
        this.streamReceiver = Source.ActorRef<ByteString>(128, Akka.Streams.OverflowStrategy.Fail)
            .To(StreamConverters.FromOutputStream(() => this.stream, true))
            .Run(Context.Materializer());
        Context.Watch(this.streamReceiver);

        Receive<ByteString>((message) => ReceivedStreamChunk(message));
        Receive<Messages.StreamComplete>((message) => ReceivedStreamComplete(message));
        Receive<Terminated>((message) => ReceivedTerminated(message));
        ReceiveAny((message) => ReceivedAnyMessage(message));
    }
    private void ReceivedTerminated(Terminated message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[receiver] {message.ActorRef.Path.ToStringWithoutAddress()} terminated, local stream length {(this.stream.CanRead ? this.stream.Length : -1)}");
    }
    private void ReceivedStreamComplete(Messages.StreamComplete message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[receiver] got signaled that the stream completed, local stream length {this.stream.Length}");
    }
    private void ReceivedStreamChunk(object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[receiver] got chunk, previous stream length {this.stream.Length}");
        this.streamReceiver.Forward(message);
    }
    private void ReceivedAnyMessage(object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[receiver] got message {message.GetType().FullName}");
    }
}
```

But the `MemoryStream` is filled async and when the `streamReceiver` terminates it closes the stream so I cannot get the data.

How can I retrieve the stream properly?

---

**Update** I got it locally working:

Thanks to input from Horusiath in Akka.NET's gitter channel I was able to directly receive the `ByteStrings`,  not necessary to use Akka.Stream there.

```
Receive<ByteString>((message) => ReceivedStreamChunk(message));
```

And:

```
private void ReceivedStreamChunk(ByteString message)
{
    var bytes = message.ToArray();
    targetStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Console.WriteLine($"[receiver] got chunk, now stream length {this.stream.Length}");
}
```

Note that Akka.NET 1.3 will add the methods `WriteTo(Stream)` and `WriteToAsync(Stream, CancellationToken)` to `ByteString`.

Still this does not work with remote actors as the receiving actor system gets this error (Serializer is Hyperion):

> Error [No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]

Actually `ByteString` has a parameterless constructor but it is `protected`.

I take it that `ByteString` is not serializable?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a remote actor when converting the `ByteString` to `byte[]` by inserting a transformation flow between the source and the sink.

Example:

`FileIO.FromFile(...).Via(Flow.Create<ByteString>().Select(x => x.ToArray())).To(...)`

Comment: I came to this question as I have the same need: Send a file from one actor to another, remote, actor. I also found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545111/1060314 Specifically **In general sources and sinks working with actor refs have not been designed to work over remote connections - they don't cover message retries, which can cause deadlocks in your system if some stream control message won't be passed in.** Which seems that StreamsRefs in 1.4 solve.