# Akka.Net Streams and remoting (Sink.ActorRefWithAck)

Tags: akka-stream, akka.net, akka-remoting

I've made quite a simple implementation with Akka.net Streams using `Sink.ActorRefWithAck`: a subscriber asks for a large string to a publisher which sends it by slices.
It works perfectly fine locally (UT) but *not remotely*. And I cannot understand what's wrong? Concretly: the subscriber is able to send the request to the publisher which responds with an `OnInit` message but then the `OnInit.Ack` will never goes back to the publisher. This `Ack` message ends up as a **dead letter**:

```
INFO  Akka.Actor.EmptyLocalActorRef - Message Ack from akka.tcp://OutOfProcessTaskProcessing@localhost:12100/user/Streamer_636568240846733287 to akka://OutOfProcessTaskProcessing/user/StreamSupervisor-0/StageActorRef-0 was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
```

Note that the log is from the destination actor so the message is handled in the right process. There is no obvious path error.

Looking at the publisher code which does not handle this message, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
    public static void ReplyWithStreamedString(IUntypedActorContext context, string toStream, int chunkSize = 2000)
    {
        Source<string, NotUsed> source = Source.From(toStream.SplitBy(chunkSize));
        source.To(Sink.ActorRefWithAck<string>(context.Sender, new StreamMessage.OnInit(),
                new StreamMessage.OnInit.Ack(),
                new StreamMessage.Completed(),
                exception => new StreamMessage.Failure(exception.Message)))
            .Run(context.System.Materializer());
    }
```

Here is the subscriber code:

```
public static Task<string> AskStreamedString(this ICanTell self, object message, ActorSystem context, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        if (timeout.HasValue)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout.Value);
            ct.Token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
        }

        var props = Props.Create(() => new StreamerActorRef(tcs));
        var tempActor = context.ActorOf(props, $"Streamer_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");

        self.Tell(message, tempActor);

        return tcs.Task.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            context.Stop(tempActor);
            if(task.IsCanceled)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            if (task.IsFaulted)                    
                throw task.Exception.GetBaseException();
            return task.Result;
        });
    }

    internal class StreamerActorRef : ReceiveActor
    {
        readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> _tcs;

        private readonly StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        public StreamerActorRef(TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs)
        {
            _tcs = tcs;
            Ready();
        }

        private void Ready()
        {
            ReceiveAny(message =>
            {
                switch (message)
                {
                    case StreamMessage.OnInit _:
                        Sender.Tell(new StreamMessage.OnInit.Ack());
                        break;
                    case StreamMessage.Completed _:
                        string result = _stringBuilder.ToString();
                        _tcs.TrySetResult(result);
                        break;
                    case string slice:
                        _stringBuilder.Append(slice);
                        Sender.Tell(new StreamMessage.OnInit.Ack());
                        break;
                    case StreamMessage.Failure error:
                        _tcs.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException(error.Reason));
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

With messages:

```
public class StreamMessage
{
        public class OnInit
        {
            public class Ack{}
        }

        public class Completed { }

        public class Failure
        {
            public string Reason { get; }

            public Failure(string reason)
            {
                Reason = reason;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general sources and sinks working with actor refs have not been designed to work over remote connections - they don't cover message retries, which can cause deadlocks in your system if some stream control message won't be passed in.

The feature you're looking for is called **StreamRefs** (which works like actor refs, but for streams), and will be shipped as part of v1.4 release (see [github pull request](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/3321) for more details).

Comment: Ok, thank you for this precision. I think it deserved to be mentioned in the documentation. Also, I've implemented a workaround using a  simple publisher actor.

Comment: Publisher actor is also fragile, as it doesn't have retry semantics. So if a control message (i.e. request for more events) won't be delivered once, your publisher will never send any more events, as it didn't receive request to do so. You'll end up with deadlocked stream.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain well: I did it using a standard ReceiveActor that acts as a publisher i.e. A very classic implementation